# Asyncio semaphores and queues : how to share a queue between multiple consumers

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

I'm new to asyncio and I'm having some troubles sharing a queue from a producer with several consumers. Basically what I want to do is to add as many consumers as I want, each with a specific limit (a Semaphore).

In the code below, limiting the consumer2 (C2) with 1 item doesn't work. Could you please explain me why?

```
import asyncio
import random

filenames = {"A":1,"B":2,"C":1,"D":2,"E":1,"F":1,"G":2,"H":1,"I":2,"J":2}

async def producer(f, d, q):
    print("producing {}".format(f))
    t = random.randint(4,15)
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    res = f,d
    await q.put(res)
    print(f,d, "queued in {} secs".format(t))

async def consumer1(item):
    print("got {} : C1".format(item))
    t = 10
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    print(item, "processed by C1 in {} secs".format(t))

async def consumer2(item):
    async with asyncio.Semaphore(1):  # doesn't work here ...
        print("got {} : C2".format(item))
        t = 10
        await asyncio.sleep(t)
        print(item, "processed by C2 in {} secs".format(t))

async def manager(f, d):
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    asyncio.ensure_future(producer(f, d, q))
    item = await q.get()
    if item is None:
        pass
    if item[1] < 2:
        r1 = await asyncio.ensure_future(consumer1(item))
    else:
        r2 = await asyncio.ensure_future(consumer2(item))


async def main(filenames):
    jobs = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(manager(f, d))
        for (f, d) in filenames.items()
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*jobs)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main(filenames))
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your consumer2() creates a new Semaphore every time when you call it. You should create one instance a Semaphore in your manager() and pass it as argument to consumer() with every call.